# AVCaptureSession, AVCaptureAudioDataOutput and background Music

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I record audio/video with `AVFoundation` using `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` and `AVCaptureAudioDataOutput`. But when I add my `AVCaptureAudioDataOutput` to my `AVCaptureSession`, `AVFoundation` stop background music (in my case from iPod app).

So I'm looking for a solution to let my music playing during my record ?

Thanks,

Alak

ps: I'm targeting iOS8 and I use Swift 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    do {
      try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, withOptions: [AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.MixWithOthers, AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.DefaultToSpeaker])
      try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

    } catch {
      print("error")
    }

    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
```

Comment: I know this answer is really old, but this makes the music stutter when starting/stopping the capture session. Is there a way to let the `AVCaptureAudioDataOutput` activate the audio session on the fly, shortly before starting a video recording? The Snapchat app manages to do it that way, causing no music interruption when opening/closing the camera but only when starting to record.

Comment: I have created a new SO question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67807394/5281431