# Recording video with audio using "AVCaptureSession" while background music is playing (iTunes, Spotify)

Tags: ios, swift, audio, video, avcapturesession

I am trying to record videos with audio (using "AVCaptureSession") while background music keeps playing from any music player such as iTunes or Spotify.

The CameraViewController is the the default page, so it would be convenient not to pause the user's background music while he/she records a video.

Really hoping someone can help with this issue.

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32480732/avcapturesession-avcaptureaudiodataoutput-and-background-music?rq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869802/avcapturesession-and-background-audio-ios-7), maybe it will be useful for you.