# iOS Camera: `AVCaptureAudioDataOutput` activate audio session on the fly, avoid background music stutter

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I have created a Camera using AVFoundation which is able to record video and audio using `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` and `AVCaptureAudioDataOutput`. I create my capture session, attach all inputs and the video- and audio-data outputs, and the Camera then sits idle. The user is now able to start a video recording.

#### Problem

The problem with this is that immediately after I start the capture session (`captureSession.startRunning()`), the background music stutters. I assume this is because once the capture session starts running, the `AVCaptureAudioDataOutput` internally activates the AVAudioSession ([`AVAudioSession.setActive(...)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/1616627-setactive)), which I don't want it doing. I want it sitting idle (and not providing any audio output buffers) until I explicitly activate the Audio Session (once the user starts recording).

This is really annoying, since the Camera is the start-screen in our app and everytime the user opens or closes the app his music stutters.

I know that this is somehow possible because Snapchat works that way - you open the App and background audio smoothly continues to play. Once you start recording, there is a small stutter on the background music, but the Camera smoothly operates and starts recording once the short stutter is over.

My code:

```swift
func configureSession() {

    captureSession.beginConfiguration()

    // Video, Photo and Audio Inputs
    ...

    // Video Output
    ...

    // Audio Output
    audioOutput = AVCaptureAudioDataOutput()
    guard captureSession.canAddOutput(audioOutput!) else {
      throw CameraError.parameter(.unsupportedOutput(outputDescriptor: "audio-output"))
    }
    audioOutput!.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: audioQueue)
    captureSession.addOutput(audioOutput!)

    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord,
                                                    options: [.mixWithOthers,
                                                              .allowBluetoothA2DP,
                                                              .defaultToSpeaker,
                                                              .allowAirPlay])

    captureSession.commitConfiguration()
}
```

#### What I tried

##### Delay configuring the `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()`

I tried to first configure the `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance` with the category `AVAudioSession.Category.playback`, and switch to `.playAndRecord` once I want to start recording audio.

This didn't work and the `AVCaptureSessionRuntimeError` event gets invoked immediately after starting the Camera with the Error code `-10851`, which means `kAudioUnitErr_InvalidPropertyValue`. I think this means that the `AVCaptureAudioDataOutput` is not allowed to record from the Audio Session, but I don't event want to do that right now - it should just be idle.

##### Delay adding the `AVCaptureAudioDataOutput` output

I tried to not add the audio output (`AVCaptureAudioDataOutput`) in the beginning, and only add it "on-demand" once the user starts recording, and while that worked fine for the background music (no stutter when starting, only short stutter once the user starts recording, exactly how I want it), it made the Preview freeze for a short amount of time (because the Capture Session is being reconfigured via `beginConfiguration` + audio output adding + `commitConfiguration`)

Does anyone know how it's possible to achieve what I'm trying to do here - or how Snapchat does it? Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out. I simply created a separate `AVCaptureSession` specifically for the audio input/output which I synchronize with the main capture session's `masterClock`. I can then start/stop the secondary capture session on the fly (shortly before start recording)

Comment: Nice touch with the synchronization! Can you accept your answer?

Comment: could you please provide the code result to achieve this?  it would be great. im trying also to do like snapchat with the video preview right after the record. but the background music is killed when I launch the app and the video preview is freezed

Comment: @nicover Sure, to your luck the entire thing is open-source: https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera

Comment: Revisiting this post right now since I somehow can't manage to build the same thing again, audio and video is always out of sync... Not sure how I achieved that 2 years ago lol

Answer (score 0):

The `.mixWithOthers` looks like the right thing to do to avoid interruptions, but default `AVCaptureSession` will configure the  `AVAudioSession` for you, so set

`captureSession.automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession = false`

to stop it replacing your settings.

The property's documentation tells us that `AVCaptureSession` does more than just set the `.playAndRecord` category, a fact which may be important for your use case:

> the receiver ensures the application's audio session is set to the PlayAndRecord category, and picks an appropriate microphone and polar pattern to match the video camera being used

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already disabled the automatic configuration. See my answer for the actual solution